# Can't import my own module distributed with distutils

Tags: python, pip, importerror, distutils

I'd like to package my application to share it between several projects.
My setup.py looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='foo_bar',
    version='1.0',
    py_modules=['foo_bar'],
    install_requires=[
        'bitstring==3.1.5',
        'pytz==2016.4',
        'wheel==0.24.0', ]
)
```

Then I run command

```
python setup.py sdist
```

that creates tar.gz file for me

I'm having trouble with using my foo_bar application. I'm installing it into separate virtualenv via pip

```
pip install dist/foo_bar.tar.gz
```

and output of pip freeze suggests that it is installed

```
foo-bar==1.0
bitstring==3.1.5
pytz==2016.4
wheel==0.24.0
```

When I try to import this module in python console

```
import foo_bar
```

I get `ImportError: No module named 'foo_bar'`

What I'm missing?

Edit:

My file structure looks like this:

```
foo_bar
├── dist
│   └── foo_bar-1.0.tar.gz
├── __init__.py
├── MANIFEST
├── bar.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
```

Comment: Have you also tried ``python setup.py install``? Could you provide your directory structure? Are you in the same virtualenv when you're trying to import your module? Why are you using ``py_modules``  and not ``packages``? It's much more flexible...

Comment: @ziky I've updated my post to include directory structure. I'm using separate virtualenv, but have installed foo_bar there. TBH, I haven't heard of 'packages' option, could using it instead of py_module make a difference?

Comment: you're trying to import ``foo_bar``, however there is no ``foo_bar.py`` in your package! Try to rename ``bar.py`` to that name. However I've never used packages this way. Usually you create a package (directory with ``__init__.py`` file) on the same level as ``setup.py`` is. This means, that you would create another ``foo_bar`` dir in you project and there you would place ``bar.py``. Then you would import it like ``import foo_bar.bar``.

Comment: Creating module foo_bar on the same level as `setup.py` and moving there all python files (beside `setup.py` and `MANIFEST`) did the trick. Thanks, if you combine your two comments into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide your directory structure? Are you in the same virtualenv when you're trying to import your module? Why are you using `py_modules` and not `packages`?

Moreover, you're trying to import `foo_bar`, however there is no `foo_bar.py` in your package! Try to rename `bar.py` to that name.

Note: I've never used packages this way. Usually you create a package (directory with `__init__.py` file) on the same level as `setup.py` is. This means, that you would create another `foo_bar` dir in you project and there you would place `bar.py`. Then you would import it like `import foo_bar.bar`.